# Parsing text and compile rules and should be used for validation of Input XML file

Tags: java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
<MajorTag>
    <param>
        <name>
            NameFiled
        </name>
  <!-- Below value can be of of pattern [#(a-z0-9)] -->
        <value>

            #abcd
        </value>
    </param>
    <param>
        <name>
            Field2
        </name>
        <value>
            <!-- Below value can have [0,1]or  [,2] or just one vlaue like 
       1 wihout braces -->
            [1, 2]
        </value>
    </param>
</MajorTag>
 </Root>
```

Tried to write rules in the below format

Rulefile

```
Tag:Majortag
Parameter:NameFiled
RuleType:Simple
Rules:{Rule1:AlphaNumeric(6-8), Rule2:StartsWith(#)}


TAG:MajorTag
Parameter:Field2
RuleType:Complex
PositionalParameter:[Mandatory, Optional]
PosiotnalParameterRules:[postion1Rules:{Rule1:Number(1), Rule2:ValueList(0,1,2)}, postion2Rules:{Rule1:Number(1), Rule2:ValueList(0,1)}]
NonPosiotnalParameterRules:{Rule1:Number(1), Rule2:ValueList(0,1,2)}
```

But could not get idea to parse this type of text file and compile rules

I want to Have a simple Rule format for the above mentioned xml
Each parameter has been tagged as name and value.
For the given parameter name I should be able to write the rules and validate the value in the input file.

Need to write code for rule compiler as well as as validation of the same.

Comment: ... why not use an XSD?

Comment: XSD the end user does not want to learn that format. They are looking for easy text format where any user can change the rules when required.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
 <MajorTag>
  <param>
   <name>
    NameFiled
   </name>
   <value>
    <!-- Below value can be of of pattern [#(a-z0-9)] -->
    #abcd
   </value>
  </param>
  <param>
   <name>
    Field2
   </name>
   <value>
    <!-- Below value can have [0,1]or  [,2] or just one vlaue like 1 wihout braces -->
    [1, 2]
   </value>
  </param>
 </MajorTag>
</Root>

Comment: I'm not sure that this is simpler than XSD. Also there exist many XSD editors to make creating XSDs easier.

Comment: I had showed a XSD format and they did not agree for it.

Comment: Maybe you could make this simplified format (which doesn't look too simple right now) compile into XSD? You could get rid of some of the verbosity of XSD, especially for the common cases, but still have the benefit of being able to use all existing tools that work with XSD. That would actually be pretty cool and useful. Anyway, for parsing a language you can use a [finite state machine](https://medium.com/@brianray_7981/tutorial-write-a-finite-state-machine-to-parse-a-custom-language-in-pure-python-1c11ade9bd43).

Comment: Yes internally for validation I can use XSD. First need to parse the rule and then convert to XSD then I can use it for validation of XML.

Comment: Also just started with Rule file format still thinking how better it can be simplified any idea or lead would be hlepful

Comment: Are these rules *only* for validating content of elements, and not for validating the structure of the document? If so, then you might actually just compile to XPath to find the elements in question and REGEX or such to validate their content. User could specify `Path:"Root\MajorTag\param\value";  Format:"#[a-z0-9]+";` or something like that. If you do need to validate the document structure, then XSD is probably required.

Comment: Yes only the content of the value needs to be validated for each parameter. There are may be around 10 to 15 major tags and each tag may have 10 to 15 different type of parameters and they did not agree for regex patter as they find it difficult. So internally I need to convert text rules to regex.

Comment: Cool, so XPath and REGEX are probably your best bet then. For the client, specifying the direct path to the element should be easy enough (it's about as simple as you can get). And if REGEX is too hard for them then you might provide a simplification of it with your stuff like `StartsWith(#), AlphaNumeric(6-8)`. The format would just be two parts: the path and the format. With a simple format like this, writing the rules and parsing the rules should hopefully be pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Let me try this and propose.

Comment: Also, I just noticed. It looks like your `<name>` determines the format of the `<value>`, so in that case you'll need to use XPath like this `//param/name[text()='NameFiled']/following-sibling::value[1]/text()` then check the resulting value with your REGEX. That XPath might be complicated, but in that case you can provide a simpler format and compile to the real XPath internally. Best of luck! See here: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/5a962a20cfb0afbb8ae5298eac6edb1a